# Create custom task panes using Vsto Addin in C# using ribbon xml only

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

Can we create a custom task pane in C# using ribbon xml ?
Lets say i have a button button1 in ribbion xml in outlook on click of this button i want to open a Custom task pane that opens a pane with many fields is there a way of doing so?

Comment: Yes. Simplest would be for you to define the custom task pane in the VSTO project then simply display it with the code for the ribbon control. There should be an example of that in the VSTo documentation on MSDN.